# query about "dumpsys meminfo" in android

Tags: android, memory

When I run "adb shell dumpsys meminfo" on android 4.2, I get the result like

> ```
>                                  Shared  Private     Heap     Heap     Heap
>                Pss    Dirty    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
>             ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
>    Native       28        8       28    16404    12256     3663
>    Dalvik    14062    10060    13736    20032    15254     4778
>    Cursor        0        0        0                           
>    Ashmem        0        0        0                           
> Other dev     4762     9556        0                           
>  .so mmap    11699     1824     1500                           
> .jar mmap        0        0        0                           
> .apk mmap      368        0        0                           
> .ttf mmap      811        0        0                           
> .dex mmap     3736        0        0                               
> Other mmap      114       16       32                           
>    Unknown    12064      544    12052                           
>      TOTAL    47644    22008    27348    36436    27510     8441
> ```

I have read the page of [How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/), but still have several questions:

- Why the native Pss, shared dirty private dirty is very small?
- the heap size should be smaller than Pss?
- What does Unknown mean? Seems very big.
- If I want to know how much memory my app uses, which data should I use? The Total Pss? But it doesn't include the native Pss which is nealy zero?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the question [How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android).
I would also like you to refer to [Detail VSS,RSS,PSS,USS](http://mysuperbaby.iteye.com/blog/1390151) link. The most appropriate data to use for a particular app is 
USS (Unique Set Size ) as

> USS is the total private memory for a process, i.e. that memory that is completely unique to that process . USS is an extremely useful number because it indicates the true incremental cost of running a particular process. When a process is killed, the USS is the total memory that is actually returned to the system. USS is the best number to watch when initially suspicious of memory leaks in a process.

which you can get by `adb shell procrank | grep <your.package.name>`